# Just upgraded to OS X Server 5.1 and can't get my mail with imap-login: Info: Aborted login (user disabled)?

Tags: mac-osx-server

Getting this in the logs:

Apr 14 16:29:48 imap-login: Info: Aborted login (user disabled): user=, method=DIGEST-MD5, rip=10.0.10.14, lip=10.0.1.9, TLS: Disconnected

Any ideas?

Comment: Read the log. Try to understand it. And then check the user record and why it might be disabled.

Comment: And are you sure you really want DIGEST-MD5 as Auth Method?